# C++ Pointer Question

Tags: c++, pointers

I apologize since this is rather a n00bish question, but I can't figure this one out.

```
class View //simplified
{
public:
  ROILine* ROI() {return _roi;} //setter does some control stuff...
private:
  ROILine *_roi;
}

class ROI : public eq::Object
{

public:
    //virtual ROI(ROI* copy) = 0;
    virtual ~ROI() {};

    virtual uint32_t getType() = 0;

    virtual void reset() = 0;

    virtual bool addPoint( eq::Vector3f point ) = 0;
    virtual bool previewPoint( eq::Vector3f point ) = 0;

    virtual bool getNotationLocation( eq::Vector3f& point ) = 0;

    virtual bool draw() = 0;

protected:

    enum ROIType {
        NONE = 0,
        LINE,
        POLY,
        AREA,
        VOLUME
    };

    enum ROIMeasure {
        RM_LENGTH = 1,
        RM_AREA,
        RM_VOLUME,
    };

private:

};


class ROILine : virtual public ROI
{

public:
    ROILine();
    ROILine(ROILine* copy);
    ROILine(const ROILine& copy);
    virtual ~ROILine() {SFLog(@"Destroying ROILine: 0x%x",this);};
    void reset();

    float distance() { return _start.distance(_end); }


    // ROI Interface
    uint32_t getType() { return ROI::LINE; }
    virtual bool draw();
    bool addPoint( eq::Vector3f point );
    bool previewPoint( eq::Vector3f point );
    bool getNotationLocation( eq::Vector3f& point );

    eq::net::DataOStream& serialize(eq::net::DataOStream& os) ;
    eq::net::DataIStream& deserialize(eq::net::DataIStream& is) ;

protected:

    enum ROILineState { // RLS_
        RLS_RESET,
        RLS_START,
        RLS_PREVIEW,
        RLS_END,
    };

private:
    uint32_t _state;
    eq::Vector3f _start;
    eq::Vector3f _end;
};

ROILine::ROILine(const ROILine& copy) : ROI()
{
    reset();
    switch (copy._state) 
    {
        case RLS_PREVIEW:
        case RLS_END:
            addPoint(eq::Vector3f(copy._start));
            addPoint(eq::Vector3f(copy._end));
            break;
        case RLS_START:
            addPoint(eq::Vector3f(copy._start));
            break;
        case RLS_RESET:
        default:
            break;
    }
}

/*!
 @abstract resets the line values and state
 */
void ROILine::reset()
{
    _state = RLS_RESET;
    _end = eq::Vector3f::ZERO;
    _start = eq::Vector3f::ZERO;
}
/*!
 @abstract if it has 2 points, draw the line. (_state > _PREVIEW)
 @discussion assumes GL is already set up.  Executes drawing commands.
 @result true if the line was drawn
 */
bool ROILine::draw()
{
    bool retVal = false;

    if (_state >= RLS_PREVIEW) {
        //glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f); //Back Up?
        glColor3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );  //Red
        glEnable( GL_LINE_SMOOTH );
        glLineWidth( 1 );
        glBegin( GL_LINES );
        {
            glVertex3fv( _start.array );
            glVertex3fv( _end.array );
        }
        glEnd();    
        //glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Return
        retVal =  true;
    } 

    return retVal;

}

// Elsewhere...

View *v = getView(); // returns the view object

// Destroys each time, but works wonderfully
ROILine r = ROILine(*(v->ROI()));
r.draw();

// Does not work (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)
v->ROI()->draw();

// Does not work (EXC_BAD_ACCESS on draw());
ROILine *r = v->ROI();
r->draw(); // debug shows r != 0x0
```

The Errors I get are as follows when I break on `r->draw()` and continue.

```
[Switching to process 12453]
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c++
Warning: the current language does not match this frame.
(gdb) continue 
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
```

The `"EXC_BAD_ACCESS"` occurs on `r->draw()` or `v->ROI()->draw()`  It doesn't step into the program at all, just halts and `bt` gives me a `??`

My copy constructor works, because the draw() function actually draws where it's supposed to (instead of !!@#$!4!#@ land)  What I don't udnerstand, is why copying the value works, but accessing `v->ROI()->draw()` does not.  it *MUST* have `v->ROI()` in order to make the copy!!

yes? ... no?

so confused...

Thanks,

Comment: If possible, please try to come up with a small but fully compileable example that demonstrates the problem. It's hard to follow what's going on with so much code removed.

Comment: @Tyler, uh, compilable?  no.  That's 10k lines of code just to include the distributed objects library.

Comment: @aaa carp, I put up destructors for ROI and ROILine.

Comment: @Stephen Furlani: So you stub stuff out.  You need to simplify the code until you can isolate the problematic parts. (BTW, do you have non-default copy constructors?  If so, provide code for those too.)

Comment: @jamesdlin this is a question about why the Copy Constructor work, but referencing the variable directly by pointer does not.  All my code's logic works.  And obviously `v->ROI()` returns the correct value of _roi because it's able to *copy* it.  Why doesn't referencing it work!?  This is more of a language question than a logic or programmatic question.

Comment: Does ROILine have a copy constructor or is it using a compliler-generated one? Does the crash happen as `v->ROI()->draw()` calls into `draw` or does it happen somewhere inside of `draw`? If it happens inside of `draw` can you debug into there to determine which exact line is triggering the crash?

Comment: Hm we cant tell you whats wrong since your example code does not contain failures? ;-)

Comment: Is ROI the base class for ROILine? I don't see any inheritance here, why is there a ROI class anyway.

Comment: It's impossible to tell why this doesn't work, This code shows no initialization of _roi in the View class, there's no copy constructor, no class inherits from the ROI class, etc.

Comment: @Stephen Furlani: No, just because your copy constructors *seem* to work does not mean that they are necessarily correct.  For example, they could be taking ownership of pointers that are freed when the copy is destroyed.  It's hard to tell with the abridged code you've provided.

Comment: More code placed up.  Hopefully it's enough.

Comment: Use the most pedantic flags and show us the warnings given by the compiler !

Comment: @wok - you'll forgive my c++ n00bness.  I've got -Wall -Wextra -Wmost on in XCode (this is technically an Objective-C++ program)  And I don't get any warnings in View, ROI, ROILine, or the class that calls `r->draw()`

Comment: @Stephen Like jamesdlin said, you need to simplify things down to something *representative* of the error. There's no simple answer to the question "why can I copy but not dereference?" because of course that *shouldn't* happen. It means there's an error in your code somewhere. Your question is being downvoted because you are expecting people to make guesses based on haphazard snippets from a large codebase rather than expending some effort of your own to isolate the problematic code into a small test case that can be fully understood and discussed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that everything in your copy constructor for `ROILine` is working correctly, then here is a possibility: Something has overwritten a few bytes of the `ROILine` instance returned by `View::ROI()`.

Most likely, the first several bytes of a `ROILine` object contain a pointer to the virtual function table for that class. (At least this is what typical C++ implementations do.) If those bytes get overwritten then instead of calling through the virtual function table, the program would end up calling through garbage and would almost certainly crash.

However, when making a copy of an object through a copy constructor, that pointer to the virtual function table is probably not accessed at all (unless you were to make a call to a virtual function in the copy constructor). In that case, all the data is copied successfully to a new object that has a correct vtable pointer.

Since `draw` is vritual, this would explain why calling it on the copy works while calling it on the original does not.

If this is what is happening, then you need to figure out what is overwriting part of your `ROILine` instance. If that instance is part of another object, then it may be easy. If that instance has been heap allocated individually, then it could be somewhat harder.

Comment: I upvoted you and @Chris Dodd for pointing me to the vtable.  Turns out the `operator>>` wasn't getting called and the object wasn't getting streamed in.  Used a call to `_roi->deserialize(ostream& os)` and now it works.  Just have to figure out why the `operator>>` isn't working.

Comment: @Stephen That sounds a bit odd. A deseralization function shouldn't be touching the vtable pointer.

Comment: I confess to not knowing enough about C++ to even make that call.  One of the reasons I hate working in this language.  Whatever the reason, it works.

Comment: the source of the issue was that the `operator>>` method wasn't being called because I didn't declare it as `inline.`  Instead of using the `>>` the stream object had default behavior which just copied the object improperly.  Thus, downstream, things got overwritten that shouldn't have been.  Now it's fixed, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think there's something strange going on.

You said code containing this line works wonderfully:

```
 ROILine r = ROILine(*(v->ROI()));
```

In this line you perform `*(v->ROI())` successfully.

But you said that if you try to do `ROILine *r = v->ROI()` then the value of r is NULL.

I don't think these can both be true (because that would mean you've successfully dereferenced a NULL pointer). I can think of two reasons for this:

1. Calling them sequentially does not work. If you move the "works wonderfully" block below the others, does it fail? If so, you may be copying a pointer and destroying it or the data it refers to. Then later, the data is not accessible.

   The private ROILine* member of the View class is not set or initialized properly. Sometimes, this can lead to strange stochastic behavior; one compiled version (with the "works wonderfully block") may randomly initialize that member to be a nonzero value, while another compiled version (with one of the failing blocks) may randomly initialize that member to be zero. I've heard this referred to as a "Heisenbug" because trying to print out debugging information may change the problem.

Also, make sure you've verified that r is NULL *after* the line setting its value is executed. Some compilers initialize pointers to NULL and it may have not been set yet. Also check to make sure you have optimizations turned off; sometimes debuggers don't play well with optimizations, which can make a line of code execute after you think it's been executed.

Comment: uhm, I'm pretty sure I said `r != 0x0`

Comment: So what is r? And do not tell us it is number 6!

Comment: Oops-- replace "NULL" with the value you get when the pointer is deemed unsafe. Check to see how this value changes when the different blocks are used (non-sequentially).

Answer (score 1):

The symptoms make it sound like your ROILine object has been deleted, leaving you with a dangling pointer to freed memory.  When you try to call a virtual function, it crashes, because the vtable has been overwritten, but when you create a copy with the copy constructor it gets at least some valid data from the freed object, and appears to work.

Comment: The instance's vtable pointer is what could be overwritten, not just "the vtable". But otherwise, this is certainly a possibility.

Comment: Thanks.  The vtable is getting overwritten because my `operator>>` isn't being compiled for some reason - and with no warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I think ROILine should inherit from ROI.
Make draw virtual in ROILine and then

ROILine *r = v->ROI();
r->draw(); // debug shows r != 0x0

should work...

Connected to the problem (or not) It's a bad practice to call a function returning your ROI exactly like ROI constructor.

(referring to: ROILine* ROI() {return _roi;} //setter does some control stuff... )

Maybe the compiler gets confused...

Comment: If the compiler was confused between `View::ROI()` and `ROI::ROI()` then `v->ROI()` should result in a syntax error and not compile at all (unless it was a really strange and crappy compiler).

Answer (score 0):

Your copy constructor works as it takes a reference, and to do this you feed it a dereferenced (possibly null) pointer. This is one of those funny things in the language, as a reference to a dereferenced pointer doesn't actually dereference the pointer until you use the reference (C++ really is multi paradigm, it's even lazy!). Since this is undefined behavior, its only by chance that the copy constructor works at all. Its possible that in the View you've invalidated the pointer somehow.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int addOne(int const & n) {
    return n + 1; // Uh oh.
}

int main() {
    int * ptr = 0;
    cout << addOne(*ptr) << endl; // Doesn't crash here.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just thought that I should clarify: It's not actually lazy. That's just a tongue-in-cheek comment. :)